# How can I make a Dialog box appear when any app is launch in Android Phone in Android Studio

Tags: java, xml

I have also taken usage permission and display on other app permission from the user, but I am not able to detect which app is opened. Can you help me? When any app is launched, a dialog box appears.

I want that when any app is opened like YouTube Instagram Facebook then a dialog box should appears when  app open.  I tried a lot for this but it is not happening please solve my problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.